# Identical Manjaro installs different (How to KDE/Plasma clone?)

Tags: kde-plasma, manjaro

I have the exact same install of Manjaro Plasma on two computers, a laptop (#1) and a desktop (#2), but the two GUIs look different.  #1 is fine; all the icons show in the panel and the dolphin window is a solid, normal color.

As well as using "konsave" to copy the GUI, I have also copied all the KDE, Plasma, and GTk files from #1 to #2

The settings are identical according to the config files of:

```
/usr/bin/systemsettings->Appearance
~/.gtkrc-2.0
qt5ct
```

But, still, on #2, icons are missing in the panel for common programs, like Discord, Pycharm, and Kmag, and Dolphin attacks my eyes with its unreadable and obnoxious alternate colored rows with black text on black text, and if I use split, the other window is a totally different "theme" of unreadableness.

Honestly, I am in the dark as to how Qt 4/5, GTk 2/3/3.5/4, work together on Plasma/KDE/X11, nor what all the countless rc, css, qss, etc. files actually do, but there appears to be some file that exists on #1 and not on #2 that is controlling the icons and Dolphin.  All the apps look identical (that I have tested), except Dolphin,

The icons exist in the same locations on both.

#1

```
/opt/discord/discord.png, /usr/share/app-info/icons/archlinux-arch-community/64x64/discord_discord.png, /usr/share/pixmaps/discord.png
```

#2

```
/opt/discord/discord.png, /usr/share/app-info/icons/archlinux-arch-community/64x64/discord_discord.png, /usr/share/pixmaps/discord.png
```

And just to be on the safe side, I reinstalled everything with
sudo `pacman -Qqn | sudo pacman -S -`

Any ideas?

Here's how I 'cloned' the UI (alone with konsave)

```
rsync -avr --delete .config/plasma* jw@192.168.0.6:.config
rsync -avr --delete .config/kde* jw@192.168.0.6:.config
rsync -avr --delete .config/gtk* jw@192.168.0.6:.config
rsync -avr --delete .local/share/plasma* jw@192.168.0.6:.local/share
rsync -avr --delete .local/share/kde* jw@192.168.0.6:.local/share
rsync -avr --delete .local/share/gtk* jw@192.168.0.6:.local/share
```

System:

```
CPU: 8-core Intel Core i7-10700 (-MT MCP-) speed/min/max: 2768/800/4800 MHz
Kernel: 6.1.26-1-MANJARO x86_64 Up: 2m Mem: 1967.3/48024.9 MiB (4.1%)
Storage: 2.28 TiB (40.4% used) Procs: 312 Shell: Zsh inxi: 3.3.27
```

UPDATE:  when I run dolphin from the desktop, which uses `usr/share/applications/org.kde.dolphin.desktop`, it looks ugly, but when I run it from the command line, or just as a simple openbox launcher, it looks fine.  Can anyone tell me why the desktop launcher imposes a radically different UI than the command line?   This is the launcher...

```
Exec=/bin/dolphin
Icon=system-file-manager
Type=Application
Categories=System;
```

What's even crazier is that if a create a shell script of

```
#!/bin/sh
/bin/dolphin
```

It STILL looks ugly... but if I set `QT_QPA_PLATFORMTHEME=""` (instead of the default `QT_QPA_PLATFORMTHEME=qt5ct`), it looks OK, but on #1, it still looks ok even when the var IS set.

Comment: StackOverflow is for questions related to programming. I suggest you ask this in [a more adequate community](http://unix.stackexchange.com).